Helm installation fails due to using deprecated API
I'm trying to install Artifactory Jfrog version 7.12.6 but I keep getting this error: Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [resource mapping not found for name: "jfrog-platform-postgresql" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1" ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "jfrog-platform-artifactory-nginx" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta2" ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "jfrog-platform-artifactory" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta2" ensure CRDs are installed first] It seems it's using deprecated API versions, I've tried Helm mapkubeapis Plugin but that only works for upgrading not installation, Do any suggestion what I can do to tackle this problem.
